# how to float right card-body for screen sizes over 1280 using bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap cards, I'm trying to float a card-img left and the card-body right, but the float classes aren't working for me. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row row-eq-height">
            <div class="col">

                <div class="card" style="">
                  <img class="card-img-top" style="width: 33%; float: left;" src="img/myimg.jpg" ">
                  <div class="card-img-caption">caption here</div>

                  <div class="card-body float-xl-right">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Title here</h5>
                    <p>By A Person</p>
                    <p class="card-text">When in the course of human events...</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with the `.card` class having a display of `flex`. Once that was removed, I could float the content left or right.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `xl` breakpoint is set to 1280? Because if yes, then you could just use `flex-xl-row` class on `card` element and wrap image & caption inside a `div`, so they stay together:

```
<div class="card flex-xl-row">
  <div>
    <img class="card-img-top" src="img/myimg.jpg">
    <div class="card-img-caption">caption here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Title here</h5>
    <p>By A Person</p>
    <p class="card-text">When in the course of human events...</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```